# Not a standard writer

Tags: cipher

What is the hidden message?

> n.y-o dak. orm. ugb ,cyd EKRPAT t.fxrape nafrgy

Please provide explanation to your answer!

Hint:

> Keyboard layout.

Comment: I'm not sure about "pattern" tag, so if must, please add/remove necessary tags.

Comment: Message to users who down-voted - please at least provide some comments or feedback to this question, so I could change things that seems to be wrong, incomplete or inappropriate!

Comment: Even though I didn't downvoted, but I guess it was because the puzzle is unclear. The tag doesn't match with the question. And we (atleast I) have no idea which tag to edit to. It can be cryptography, rebus or enigma.

Comment: @manshu Thanks for feedback. In a minute I will add update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The decoded message reads

> let's have some fun with DVORAK keyboard layout

Because

> The typist, used to a Dvorak keyboard layout, tries to type the message on a standard keyboard.
>  
>   [image] 
>  
>  [Dvorak Simplified Keyboard, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvorak_Simplified_Keyboard)

Comment: Great. You did it! :)

Comment: @humn - For me, the hint was the most useful bit. Dvorak was the first thing I thought of in terms of alternative keyboard layouts.